# SQL. Как объединить несколько строк в одну

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос - выдает 3 тыс. строчек, но проблема в том что в выводе у одного ID может быть 2,3 и больше строчек - т.е. допустим покупка продуктов - и где-то 1 продукт, а где-то пакет продуктов - соотвественно каждая единица товара это одна строка.

Как объединить строки по одному заказу суммирая цену каждого продукта?
Через внутренний SELECT(SUM) пробовал, к сожалению общую сумму всех покупок выдает.

```
Select o.1 as 'Дата создания заказа',
     o.2 as 'Дата доставки',
     coi.3 as 'Номер заказа',
     ((oi.4 * oi.5) + oi.6) as 'Стоимость',
     coi.7 as 'Сумма перевода ',
     co.8 as 'Дата перевода'
     from PLACE1 coi
  inner  co ON co = coi and coi is not null
  INNER JOIN  o ON o = coi
  Inner join  oi ON o = oi
  Where "доп условия"
```

Мне нужно объединить строки в 'Стоимость'

Comment: Я не понял ваш вопрос. Добавьте в вопрос минимальный пример данных, ваш запрос с `SUM`, полученный результат, и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: GROUP BY по определенным полям должен помочь

Comment: Какая у вас СУБД? Допустим в MS SQL можно так:  SUM(PRICE) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY ProductID), но вообще добавьте пример и ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, да она , сейчас попробую спасибо

Comment: @Viktorov, обновил в описании

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример, на основе моего комментария, это вам поможет:

```
create table #test_temp (id int identity(1,1), purchaseid int, productid int, price decimal(12,5))

insert #test_temp
values
(1,1,10),(1,1,10),(1,2,20),(1,3,30),(2,1,10),(2,2,20),(2,2,20)

SELECT *,sum(price) over (partition by purchaseid,productid) sumprice FROM #test_temp

DROP TABLE #test_temp
```

Подробнее: [предложение OVER](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: спасибо, то что надо